# What's wrong with this SQLite query?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I can guarantee that the database has all the columns and values I am looking for.

The query comes back with a `CursorOutOfBounds`. Does anyone have any ideas why and what I should test?

```
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE _id="+nextvalue+"" , null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    numval = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));                 
    c.close();
```

Logcat output

```
11-22 00:08:36.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25405): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The query is returning an empty result set. There are no records with the id of `nextvalue` (whatever that is). You should check that `moveToFirst()` succeeded:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    numval = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
} else {
    // no results returned
}
c.close();
```

Comment: there are. this is the problem. I have output the entire table and even checked it manually and the id value is ther

Comment: @Max: "...and the id value is ther" - so is the column called `id` or is it `_id`?

Comment: _id as android requires. Is it ok if that is not the first field in the table.

Comment: @Max - I suggest two experiments. First, use the selection args to interpolate `nextvalue` into the query (`db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE _id=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(nextvalue)})`). Second, eliminate the WHERE clause from your query and see what the query returns.

Comment: @Max - I'm not sure whether _id needs to be the first column in the table or not. It does have to have the type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 0):

Does the statement is in `bindview` of CursorAdapter ? if it is, try to remove `c.moveToFirst()`